# Howto check if two hosts are the same

Tags: networking, dns, ip

I just came across an issue, where I had to check if a path points into a windows share. Part of this problem is to check if host A is the same as host B. Where host A and host B can be one of the following {IPv4-Address, IPv6-Address, Hostname, FQDN}. As I do not need to be exact it's enough to resolve and compare the IP-Addresses in my case.

But is there, theoretically, a method to check if the hosts are the same?

Comment: Even if you knew two hosts are the same - isn't that meaningless? The two hosts could be different moments later, following DNS updates, load balancing, whatever.

Comment: Well, good point, but there are applications without load balancing and DNS updates are rare. Anyway this question is ment theoretically, without claiming to be reasonable.

Comment: I'm interested to see answers regardless :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no general method to see if two identifiers (names or addresses) go to the same host. One example: `192.0.2.1` and `2001:db8::bad:dcaf`. Are they the same? (Answer: cannot tell)

There is no general concept of host identity in the Internet. Some protocols have such a concept, for instance [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) (connect to the hosts, see if the fingerprints match) or [HIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_Identity_Protocol) (test the keys) but you depend on this protocol being activated for these specific machines.

Some heuristics may help ([fingerprinting](http://www.packetwatch.net/documents/papers/osdetection.pdf) the machine, for instance) but it will be far from 100 %.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the two addresses into the `getaddrinfo()` function, and compare the resulting lists for any matches.

Unlike `gethostbyname()`, this function will happily parse IPv6 literals, and will also return any relevant `A` or `AAAA` records associated with a host name.

Comment: I thing with this method you will get false negatives. Consider machine A has two IP-Addresses, let's say 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.2.1. The addresses don't match, but the host is the same. BTW: Same problem with MAC-Addresses.

Comment: Yes, of course you will.  There's no end of ways to defeat this sort of logic.  It can tell you that two hosts _are_ the same - it cannot prove that they _are not_.